# Can I set cache name as dynamic? if yes then how?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "testCache", key = "#name")
    @GetMapping("/test/{name}")
    public String test(@PathVariable String name) {
        System.out.println("########Test Called ###### " + name);
        return HttpStatus.OK.toString();
       }


}
```

Here cacheNames is Stirng array, if name is not exists in cacheNames then it should add first then shloud do rest of the things.

I'm using spring boot cache and I have to add cacheNames depend on request parameters.

Comment: "add first then should do rest" means add to cache before executing statements in  test method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want much flexibility:

```
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
// other imports

@RestController
public class TestController {

    private final Cache myCache;

    public TestController(@Autowired CacheManager cacheManager) {
       this.myCache = cacheManager.getCache("myCache");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test/{name}")
    public String test(@PathVariable String name) {
        return myCache.get(name, () -> {
          // your expensive operation that needs to be cached.
          System.out.println("########Test Called ###### " + name);
          return HttpStatus.OK.toString();
        });
    }


}
```

Cache name will not be dynamic in that case, but the cache key will be. And this is probably what you want.